# when does the Minkowski inequality for infinity norm become equality

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have two vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, it is well known as Minkowski inequality that:
$|x+y|_\infty \leq |x|_\infty + |y|_\infty$,
where $|x|_\infty= \underset{i=1..d}{\max} |x_i|$ with $x = \left[x_1 \dots x_d\right]^T$.

Could anyone kindly tell me when this inequality becomes equality?

I see at least that the equality happens if $x = \lambda y$ with $\lambda \geq 0$, but i have not found any other case (i.e. $x = Ay$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$?) after some hours looking for on the internet.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: $\lvert (1,0) + (1,1)\rvert_\infty = \lvert (1,0)\rvert_\infty + \lvert (1,1)\rvert_\infty$

Comment: thanks for your illustrative example, but what i would like to know if possible is a mathematical relation between $x,y$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^d$, we have $\lvert x+y\rvert_\infty = \lvert x\rvert_\infty + \lvert y\rvert_\infty$ if and only there is at least one coordinate where both $\lvert x_i\rvert = \lvert x\rvert_\infty$ and $\lvert y_i\rvert = \lvert y\rvert_\infty$, and $x_i$ and $y_i$ have the same sign (in case $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, we say $0$ has the same sign as any real number).

Comment: well, i understand, thank you.